# Where are the Ubuntu 15.10 MD5 checksum?

Tags: 15.10

I couldn't find the Ubuntu 15.10 MD5 checksum anywhere, where is it? What are the gpg signed checksums and how do I use them?

Comment: http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/lubuntu/releases/15.10/release/MD5SUMS - those are pretty useless though unless you use the gpg signed ones.

Comment: I had just find them here also: http://releases.ubuntu.com/wily/MD5SUMS . Why are they useless and how do I use the gpg signed ones?

Comment: Just found this tutorial https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM on MD5, it references gpg but doesn't explain how to use the MD5SUMS.gpg file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not have to use the MD5SUMS.gpg file.

To verify the integrity of the ISO files you can use :

MD5SUMS -> http://releases.ubuntu.com/15.10/MD5SUMS

SHA1SUMS -> http://releases.ubuntu.com/15.10/SHA1SUMS

SHA256SUMS -> http://releases.ubuntu.com/15.10/SHA256SUMS

Open a terminal in the folder containing the ISO file and execute :

EXAMPLE ->

```
md5sum ubuntu-15.10-desktop-amd64.iso
```

Compare the output with the value in the MD5SUMS link - when matching - the ISO file is valid.

Comment: So, what is the MD5SUMS.gpg file for?

Comment: @lapisdecor : It is just a signature file - nothing you can use for anything ... :)

Comment: Couldn't I  use the signature file to verify the integrity of the files?

Comment: You do not have to, but you should. The files aren't protected by https, so you should use the GPG signatures to verify the hashes.

Comment: How do you verify the hashes using the signatures? I never knew that the hashes themselves need verification!